# Getting NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0. When posting request using PHP with Swift

Tags: php, json, swift

I am getting an error when i try to post my data through php with swift that says `Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}`

What does this error mean? I resolved other issues related to using PHP with swift but i am still getting this error.

How can i fix this error?

here is my code:

```
let ADD_PROP_URL = "https://example.com/WebService/api/addProperty.php"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func addProperty(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: ADD_PROP_URL)
            
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)
            
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let propName = propName.text
        let propPrice = propPrice.text
        let propBed = propBedrooms.text
        let propLoc = propLoc.text
    
        let postParameters = "name="+propName!+"&price="+propPrice!+"&bedrooms="+propBed!+"&location="+propLoc!;
                
        request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
                
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){
            data, response, error in
                    
            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }
                
            do {
                        
                let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
            
                if let parseJSON = myJSON {
                    var msg : String!
                    msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                    print(msg)
                    print(response)
                    print(data)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                print(response)
                print(data)
        }
                    
    }
               
    task.resume()
                
    }
```

Comment: `postParameters` does not seem to valid JSON to me on first look. It does not begin with the `{` and doesn't end with `}`. I suggest printing the string built in postParameters and checking if it is valid in some JSON linter online.

Comment: @ShawnFrank i dont quite understand what you mean. can you provide a code example snippet or a tool to try ? because this is the method i found in which developers use to post paramerters from swift to PHP

Comment: Add `print("Response: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)"))` in your closureL Concerning the encoding of the `postParameters`, you are sending in the format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`.

Comment: Sure, this line of code `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` suggests you will send JSON data. Json data usually begins and ends with `[ or {` and ends with `} or ]`. Here is a tool: to check the validity of your JSON string https://jsonlint.com/ and here is some info on JSON https://www.json.org/json-en.html. I think just formatting your string properly might fix your errors.

Comment: @Larme do you have a solution for me? i really do not understand and this is my first time using php with swift

Comment: @ShawnFrank what do i type in the jsonlint.com? what should i post exactly?

Comment: @ShawnFrank can you help me in formatting the string?

Comment: Did you do `print("Response: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)"))`? And what's the output of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try the following code, and tell us what you get:

```
@IBAction func addProperty(_ sender: Any) {
    if let requestURL = URL(string: ADD_PROP_URL) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        var components = URLComponents(url: requestURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: propName.text ?? ""),
                                 URLQueryItem(name: "price", value: propPrice.text ?? "") ,
                                 URLQueryItem(name: "bedrooms", value: propBedrooms.text ?? "") ,
                                 URLQueryItem(name: "location", value: propLoc.text ?? "") ]
        
        if let query = components.url!.query {
            request.httpBody = Data(query.utf8)
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error is \(error)")
                return
            }
            if let data = data {
                print("the data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } else {
        print("bad URL: \(ADD_PROP_URL)")
    }
}
```